# Two string's which (I think) are identical do not return true when checking if the same

Tags: java, string, boolean, equals

I have two strings, one is inputted by the user and one is the name of a thread. I inputted the name which should be the same as the thread. To verify this I have the program output

```
System.out.println("DS:" + DeamonMain.threadNameFinal + "CN:" +getName());
```

Which prints

```
DS:Thread-66CN:Thread-66
```

Now these appear to be the same string. However, when I have it test the validity of this using

```
boolean factChecker = DeamonMain.threadNameFinal == getName();
System.out.println(factChecker);
```

it prints false...

Why is this? Does this have to do with getName()? How are the string different and why so?

Comment: Most-asked question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `String.equals` to compare `String` equality, not the `==` sign.

As in:

```
boolean factChecker = DeamonMain.threadNameFinal.equals(getName());
```

The `==` operator checks for reference equality, while the `equals` method checks for the equality of your `String` values.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for an older thread on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Again, and again...

Strings in Java are compared with `equals()`, not with `==`.

Change your comparison to:

```
boolean factChecker = DeamonMain.threadNameFinal.equals(getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `.equals()` method to compare strings, rather than `==`

```
boolean factChecker = DeamonMain.threadNameFinal.equals(getName());
```

The reason is that the `.equals()` tests for value equality (the strings have the same characters), while the `==` tests for reference equality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `equals()` method instead of `==`

Like this:

```
DeamonMain.threadNameFinal.equals(getName())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals()` for String comparision instead of `==` operator

```
  boolean factChecker = DeamonMain.threadNameFinal.equals(getName());
  System.out.println(factChecker);
```

`equals()` method is used for content comparison where as `==` is reference comparison.